# Increase the recurring job polling interval for hangfire and enabling/disabling the recurring job process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-services, hangfire

I am trying to create a background processor windows service using hangfire.
I would like to increase the recurring job polling interval to more than 1 minute(hard-coded by default). The reason for doing the same is that recurring polling can affect the performance of the database.
Is there a possibility to enable/disable the hangfire recurring Job feature. This is required in case there are multiple instances of the service installed.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a recurring job in Hangfire, even if you have multiple Hangfire servers, the job will not be run on two servers at the same time.

You can use Cron expression to define the frequency at which to run your job, as described in [Hangfire docs](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html):

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => YourJob(), "0 12 * */2");
```

However, your need may be to avoid triggering a job when the previous instance is still running. For this situation, I would recommend setting a flag (in the DB for example) when your job starts and removing it when it ends. Then check if the flag is present before actually starting your process.

### Update

As you stated you want to prevent the RecurringJobScheduler from running on some servers, I have looked into the code and it seems there is no option to do this.

You can check the file [BackgroundJobServer.cs](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/129707d66fde24dc6379fb9d6b15fa0b8ca48605/src/Hangfire.Core/BackgroundJobServer.cs) where the scheduler is added to the process list and the [RecurringJobScheduler.cs](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/ede9f3680637bb6297d7e059b16b0ec86a3b8088/src/Hangfire.Core/Server/RecurringJobScheduler.cs) where the DB is queried. The value of 1 minute is hardcoded, as specified in the comments.

I think your only option is the pull request you have already made :(

Comment: What i am trying to say here is multiple service instances polling the database for fetching recurring jobs is a performance hit for the database. I would like to know if hangfire supports a feature where in i can disable the recurring job scheduler from polling for selected service instances .. Concurrent Execution of the recurring jobs is not an issue in my case. Hope this helps in further explaining the issue

Comment: Any solution to above mentioned issue is highly appreciated

Comment: @PratikPushpendra Have you evaluated the performance hit you are referring to? It feels you would not gain a lot

Comment: Consider a scenario where i have 4 instances of windows service running hangfire server. Under the current circumstances, all 4 will be polling the database to fetch the recurring jobs. In my case, the database is a highly transactional one. Thus, the perfomance parameters for the database taking a hit due to 4 extra requests every minute. I would prefer to disable the recurring job polling feature for selected instances or atleast increase the polling interval. I have created a pull request on git hub with the same changes -https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/pull/776